Microsoft Graph - Accessing OnlineMeetings Transcripts - The expression cannot be evaluated
Ok I have the following C# code used in a console app:
var deviceCodeCredential = new DeviceCodeCredential(new DeviceCodeCredentialOptions
{
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
    ClientId = AzureClientID,
    TenantId = AzureTenantID,
    DeviceCodeCallback = (code, cancellation) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(code.Message);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
});

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(deviceCodeCredential, 
    new[] { "User.Read", "OnlineMeetingTranscript.Read.All" });            
var result = await graphClient.Me.OnlineMeetings.GetAsync();

When I run this I get the following error(after logging in):

Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError - The expression cannot
be evaluated.  A common cause of this error is attempting to pass a
lambda into a delegate.

In fact with all sort of combinations of things I get the same error:
graphClient.Me.OnlineMeetings["BigStringFromURL"].GetAsync()
graphClient.Me.OnlineMeetings["BigStringFromURL"].Transcripts["0"].GetAsync()
etc..

I'm confident that the rest of the application is working as I can call:
graphClient.Me.GetAsync();

Without issue, however any enumeration of the "OnlineMeetings" object results in this error. I have two big questions:

How can see the real error message being returned? This error doesn't return any meaningful information...

What am I doing incorrectly in my call to "onlineMeetings" that doesn't allow me to access or view this object?


Update 1
@Sridevi Got me close, yes two issues, the error handling and the permissions/filters are resolved by the suggested changes, however even with these two change I can't fully obtain the transcript, so as an example:
var meeting = await graphClient.Me.OnlineMeetings.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
{
    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter = "joinWebUrl eq '" + TeamsURL + "'";
});

var transcript = await graphClient.Me.OnlineMeetings[meeting.Value[0].Id].Transcripts.GetAsync();

var transcriptText = await graphClient.Me.OnlineMeetings[meeting.Value[0].Id].Transcripts[transcript.Value[0].Id].GetAsync();

If I run this I get an object:

With a NULL content, if I try to call the content item directly:

Invalid format 'application/octet-stream, application/json' specified.

I think there's just one small thing I'm missing here, I did attempt to use the code suggested but it just prints the same thing:

"Content": null,

Update 2
I've split out this issue per discussion with @Sridevi: See here

To see the real error message being returned, you can catch the exception and inspect the error details. Modify your code to include a try-catch block and log the exception details. Here is an example: try
{     var result = await graphClient.Me.OnlineMeetings.Request().GetAsync(); } catch (Exception ex) {     Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}"); }

Could you please try to access OnlineMeetings and its transcripts is by using the Id of the online meeting. Here is an example of how you can retrieve the transcripts of a specific online meeting:
var onlineMeetingId = "MSMjMCMjZDExYWQ2OGEtMWVhYS00MGFjLWJkZWItMTExNjMyNjExYzRl";             var transcripts = await graphClient.Me.OnlineMeetings[onlineMeetingId].Transcripts.Request().GetAsync();

@Prasad-MSFT I've received similar direction from GPT-4 but unfortunately the version of graph that I'm using(5.56.0) doesn't have a "Request" method available on the "Transcript" object(and when you tell GPT-4 that it goes to lala land), I just call "Transcripts.GetAsync()" directly (this does work, but see my update for further issues). Am I on the right version, this appears to be the latest version on NuGet?

Initially, I too got same error when I ran your code in my environment without catching the exception:

To know the exact error message, make use of below modified code by including try-catch method in it where I got "Forbidden" like this:
using Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors;

var deviceCodeCredential = new DeviceCodeCredential(options);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(deviceCodeCredential, scopes);

try
{
    var result = await graphClient.Me.OnlineMeetings.GetAsync();
}
catch (ODataError odataError)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Error Code: {odataError.Error.Code}");
    throw;
}

Response:

To resolve the error, make sure to add OnlineMeetings.Read permission of Delegated type that is required to list online meetings:

Now, I used below modified code to get the online meeting ID by filtering  them with joining URL:
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors;

namespace MSOnlineMeeting
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var scopes = new[] { "User.Read", "OnlineMeetingTranscript.Read.All" };
            var AzureTenantID = "tenantId";
            var AzureClientID = "appId";

            var options = new DeviceCodeCredentialOptions
            {
                AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
                ClientId = AzureClientID,
                TenantId = AzureTenantID,
                DeviceCodeCallback = (code, cancellation) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(code.Message);
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },
            };

            var deviceCodeCredential = new DeviceCodeCredential(options);
            var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(deviceCodeCredential, scopes);

            try
            {
                var result = await graphClient.Me.OnlineMeetings.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
                {
                    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter = "joinWebUrl eq 'xxxxxxxxx'";
                });

                if (result != null && result.Value != null)
                {
                    foreach (var meeting in result.Value)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Meeting ID: {meeting.Id}");
                        Console.WriteLine($"Meeting Subject: {meeting.Subject}");
                        Console.WriteLine();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No online meetings found.");
                }
            }
            catch (ODataError odataError)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error Code: {odataError.Error.Code}");
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}

Response:

You can now use this meeting ID to fetch the online meeting transcripts by running below code:
using System.Text.Json;
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors;

namespace MSOnlineMeeting
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var scopes = new[] { "User.Read", "OnlineMeetingTranscript.Read.All" };
            var AzureTenantID = "tenantId";
            var AzureClientID = "appId";

            var options = new DeviceCodeCredentialOptions
            {
                AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
                ClientId = AzureClientID,
                TenantId = AzureTenantID,
                DeviceCodeCallback = (code, cancellation) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(code.Message);
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },
            };

            var deviceCodeCredential = new DeviceCodeCredential(options);
            var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(deviceCodeCredential, scopes);

            try
            {
                var result = await graphClient.Me.OnlineMeetings["meetingID"].Transcripts.GetAsync();
                var jsonresult = JsonSerializer.Serialize(result, new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true });
                Console.WriteLine(jsonresult);
            }
            catch (ODataError odataError)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Code);
                Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}

Response:

Reference:
List transcripts - Microsoft Graph v1.0

Well this get's me most of the way there, the only part that doesn't work is the last bit, the "result" is a object that provides a URL to the transcription, but the content property is null, if I try to call that directly graphClient.Me.OnlineMeetings[meeting.Value[0].Id].Transcripts[transcript.Value[0].Id].Content.GetAsync() I get {"Invalid format 'application/octet-stream, application/json' specified."} I think there is some sort of header change that needs to be feed in... The serialization code listed above throws a different error.

Please add your modified code part and error by editing your question to make it more clear.

See my updated code :) yeah I think I'm just missing one minor thing here, I think it's resolving the content, there's just something I need to supply to "getAsync" to tell it to receive a list of bytes instead of JSON, so far I've not found what that is though and the MS documentation in C# is rather lacking on this topic(they just call it directly and it "works")...

Try setting Content-type header as text/vtt or make use of $format query parameter as mentioned in this MS Document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calltranscript-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example-2-get-a-calltranscript-content

That code snippet doesn't work for me, the "QueryParameters" returned is of type "DefaultQueryParameters"(which appears to be empty), so the for "Format" property does exist and the code won't build. Adding a contenttype header like this: requestConfiguration.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/vtt"), results in the same error.

Can you please close this query here and post a new question regarding reading call transcript content with more details and share question link here as the main ask to find real error and access transcript info is resolved?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78633506/microsoft-graph-accessing-onlinemeetings-transcripts-invalid-format-applica

Hi @DavidRogers I added modified code as answer to that new question. Please check and let me know if it works!
